# How to add percentage row to an R table

Tags: r, apply, percentage

I have a data frame that contains three categorical variables that I tabulated using the following code:

```
df = data_frame(merged$arrears, merged$mortgage_type, merged$occupancy)
apply(df, 2, table)
```

And it gave me the following list:

```
## $`merged$arrears`
## 
##     0     1     2     3     4 
## 52124  5523  2371  1538    27 
## 
## $`merged$mortgage_type`
## 
## bullet    erm linear 
##  19958  17326  18181 
## 
## $`merged$occupancy`
## 
##            btl   holiday home owner occupied 
##          12296          27996          13112
```

How can I add the percentage of each category to the count in the tables of the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the [`tabyl()` function from the janitor package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/janitor/vignettes/tabyls.html) solve your problem?

```r
library(janitor)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'janitor'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     chisq.test, fisher.test
apply(mtcars, 2, table)
#> $mpg
#> 
#> 10.4 13.3 14.3 14.7   15 15.2 15.5 15.8 16.4 17.3 17.8 18.1 18.7 19.2 19.7   21 
#>    2    1    1    1    1    2    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    2    1    2 
#> 21.4 21.5 22.8 24.4   26 27.3 30.4 32.4 33.9 
#>    2    1    2    1    1    1    2    1    1 
#> 
#> $cyl
#> 
#>  4  6  8 
#> 11  7 14 
#> 
#> $disp
#> 
#>  71.1  75.7  78.7    79  95.1   108 120.1 120.3   121 140.8   145 146.7   160 
#>     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     2 
#> 167.6   225   258 275.8   301   304   318   350   351   360   400   440   460 
#>     2     1     1     3     1     1     1     1     1     2     1     1     1 
#>   472 
#>     1 
#> 
#> $hp
#> 
#>  52  62  65  66  91  93  95  97 105 109 110 113 123 150 175 180 205 215 230 245 
#>   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   3   1   2   2   3   3   1   1   1   2 
#> 264 335 
#>   1   1 
#> 
#> $drat
#> 
#> 2.76 2.93    3 3.07 3.08 3.15 3.21 3.23 3.54 3.62 3.69  3.7 3.73 3.77 3.85  3.9 
#>    2    1    1    3    2    2    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    2 
#> 3.92 4.08 4.11 4.22 4.43 4.93 
#>    3    2    1    2    1    1 
#> 
#> $wt
#> 
#> 1.513 1.615 1.835 1.935  2.14   2.2  2.32 2.465  2.62  2.77  2.78 2.875  3.15 
#>     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 
#>  3.17  3.19 3.215 3.435  3.44  3.46  3.52  3.57  3.73  3.78  3.84 3.845  4.07 
#>     1     1     1     1     3     1     1     2     1     1     1     1     1 
#>  5.25 5.345 5.424 
#>     1     1     1 
#> 
#> $qsec
#> 
#>  14.5  14.6 15.41  15.5 15.84 16.46  16.7 16.87  16.9 17.02 17.05  17.3  17.4 
#>     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     2     1     1     1 
#> 17.42  17.6 17.82 17.98    18  18.3 18.52  18.6 18.61  18.9 19.44 19.47  19.9 
#>     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     2     1     1     1 
#>    20 20.01 20.22  22.9 
#>     1     1     1     1 
#> 
#> $vs
#> 
#>  0  1 
#> 18 14 
#> 
#> $am
#> 
#>  0  1 
#> 19 13 
#> 
#> $gear
#> 
#>  3  4  5 
#> 15 12  5 
#> 
#> $carb
#> 
#>  1  2  3  4  6  8 
#>  7 10  3 10  1  1

apply(mtcars, 2, tabyl)
#> $mpg
#>  newX[, i] n percent
#>       10.4 2 0.06250
#>       13.3 1 0.03125
#>       14.3 1 0.03125
#>       14.7 1 0.03125
#>       15.0 1 0.03125
#>       15.2 2 0.06250
#>       15.5 1 0.03125
#>       15.8 1 0.03125
#>       16.4 1 0.03125
#>       17.3 1 0.03125
#>       17.8 1 0.03125
#>       18.1 1 0.03125
#>       18.7 1 0.03125
#>       19.2 2 0.06250
#>       19.7 1 0.03125
#>       21.0 2 0.06250
#>       21.4 2 0.06250
#>       21.5 1 0.03125
#>       22.8 2 0.06250
#>       24.4 1 0.03125
#>       26.0 1 0.03125
#>       27.3 1 0.03125
#>       30.4 2 0.06250
#>       32.4 1 0.03125
#>       33.9 1 0.03125
#> 
#> $cyl
#>  newX[, i]  n percent
#>          4 11 0.34375
#>          6  7 0.21875
#>          8 14 0.43750
#> 
#> $disp
#>  newX[, i] n percent
#>       71.1 1 0.03125
#>       75.7 1 0.03125
#>       78.7 1 0.03125
#>       79.0 1 0.03125
#>       95.1 1 0.03125
#>      108.0 1 0.03125
#>      120.1 1 0.03125
#>      120.3 1 0.03125
#>      121.0 1 0.03125
#>      140.8 1 0.03125
#>      145.0 1 0.03125
#>      146.7 1 0.03125
#>      160.0 2 0.06250
#>      167.6 2 0.06250
#>      225.0 1 0.03125
#>      258.0 1 0.03125
#>      275.8 3 0.09375
#>      301.0 1 0.03125
#>      304.0 1 0.03125
#>      318.0 1 0.03125
#>      350.0 1 0.03125
#>      351.0 1 0.03125
#>      360.0 2 0.06250
#>      400.0 1 0.03125
#>      440.0 1 0.03125
#>      460.0 1 0.03125
#>      472.0 1 0.03125
#> 
#> $hp
#>  newX[, i] n percent
#>         52 1 0.03125
#>         62 1 0.03125
#>         65 1 0.03125
#>         66 2 0.06250
#>         91 1 0.03125
#>         93 1 0.03125
#>         95 1 0.03125
#>         97 1 0.03125
#>        105 1 0.03125
#>        109 1 0.03125
#>        110 3 0.09375
#>        113 1 0.03125
#>        123 2 0.06250
#>        150 2 0.06250
#>        175 3 0.09375
#>        180 3 0.09375
#>        205 1 0.03125
#>        215 1 0.03125
#>        230 1 0.03125
#>        245 2 0.06250
#>        264 1 0.03125
#>        335 1 0.03125
#> 
#> $drat
#>  newX[, i] n percent
#>       2.76 2 0.06250
#>       2.93 1 0.03125
#>       3.00 1 0.03125
#>       3.07 3 0.09375
#>       3.08 2 0.06250
#>       3.15 2 0.06250
#>       3.21 1 0.03125
#>       3.23 1 0.03125
#>       3.54 1 0.03125
#>       3.62 1 0.03125
#>       3.69 1 0.03125
#>       3.70 1 0.03125
#>       3.73 1 0.03125
#>       3.77 1 0.03125
#>       3.85 1 0.03125
#>       3.90 2 0.06250
#>       3.92 3 0.09375
#>       4.08 2 0.06250
#>       4.11 1 0.03125
#>       4.22 2 0.06250
#>       4.43 1 0.03125
#>       4.93 1 0.03125
#> 
#> $wt
#>  newX[, i] n percent
#>      1.513 1 0.03125
#>      1.615 1 0.03125
#>      1.835 1 0.03125
#>      1.935 1 0.03125
#>      2.140 1 0.03125
#>      2.200 1 0.03125
#>      2.320 1 0.03125
#>      2.465 1 0.03125
#>      2.620 1 0.03125
#>      2.770 1 0.03125
#>      2.780 1 0.03125
#>      2.875 1 0.03125
#>      3.150 1 0.03125
#>      3.170 1 0.03125
#>      3.190 1 0.03125
#>      3.215 1 0.03125
#>      3.435 1 0.03125
#>      3.440 3 0.09375
#>      3.460 1 0.03125
#>      3.520 1 0.03125
#>      3.570 2 0.06250
#>      3.730 1 0.03125
#>      3.780 1 0.03125
#>      3.840 1 0.03125
#>      3.845 1 0.03125
#>      4.070 1 0.03125
#>      5.250 1 0.03125
#>      5.345 1 0.03125
#>      5.424 1 0.03125
#> 
#> $qsec
#>  newX[, i] n percent
#>      14.50 1 0.03125
#>      14.60 1 0.03125
#>      15.41 1 0.03125
#>      15.50 1 0.03125
#>      15.84 1 0.03125
#>      16.46 1 0.03125
#>      16.70 1 0.03125
#>      16.87 1 0.03125
#>      16.90 1 0.03125
#>      17.02 2 0.06250
#>      17.05 1 0.03125
#>      17.30 1 0.03125
#>      17.40 1 0.03125
#>      17.42 1 0.03125
#>      17.60 1 0.03125
#>      17.82 1 0.03125
#>      17.98 1 0.03125
#>      18.00 1 0.03125
#>      18.30 1 0.03125
#>      18.52 1 0.03125
#>      18.60 1 0.03125
#>      18.61 1 0.03125
#>      18.90 2 0.06250
#>      19.44 1 0.03125
#>      19.47 1 0.03125
#>      19.90 1 0.03125
#>      20.00 1 0.03125
#>      20.01 1 0.03125
#>      20.22 1 0.03125
#>      22.90 1 0.03125
#> 
#> $vs
#>  newX[, i]  n percent
#>          0 18  0.5625
#>          1 14  0.4375
#> 
#> $am
#>  newX[, i]  n percent
#>          0 19 0.59375
#>          1 13 0.40625
#> 
#> $gear
#>  newX[, i]  n percent
#>          3 15 0.46875
#>          4 12 0.37500
#>          5  5 0.15625
#> 
#> $carb
#>  newX[, i]  n percent
#>          1  7 0.21875
#>          2 10 0.31250
#>          3  3 0.09375
#>          4 10 0.31250
#>          6  1 0.03125
#>          8  1 0.03125
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>